# How can I receive notifications by email using Amazon API when the customers post reviews

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-appstore

I am trying an app for owners who open shops on Amazon to receive notifications by email when there is a low-rated review and respond immediately (within 1 hour, etc.)

That is to say, when a product registered in the WEB application is reviewed, the user is immediately notified using Amazon's API.

How can I make this function using Amazon's API.